# How to search for functions with "?" "@" and "*"

Tags: front-end

I know that in order to search for a function from the notebook level, enter for example "? Log".
I also know that you can use the "@" and "*" characters.
My questions:

- what is the difference between @ and *
- are there other characters that can be used in the search.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think those wildcards are described clearly at the documentation for [Names](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html). Its usage is same to `Information`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> are there other characters that can be used in the search.

You can use many more. Any string pattern for example can be used. For example, to search for commands with only 2 letters, do

```
?"System`" ~~ _ ~~ _
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above can also be written as

```
?"*`" ~~ StringExpression[_, _]
```

To find commands with 2 letters, such as the first one is `D` you write

```
 ?"*`" ~~ StringExpression["D", _]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find commands with only 3 letters

```
?"System`" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For any context, you can use

```
 ?"*`" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _
```

And you will get all 3 letters commands in all Mathematica contexts!

If you are brave you could also use regular expressions there, but I am not that brave myself and I did not even try.

Comment: (+1) Cool, Nasser! :-)

Comment: rnotlnglgq and Nasser - thank you very much for your help, your answers helped me a lot :-)